# Set different colors based on categories when box plotting in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

Assume having the data:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val": np.random.normal(0, 1, size=100),
        "cat": np.random.choice(["a", "b"], size=100),
    }
)
```

Next, visualize a box plot:

```py
from plotly import graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df["val"], x=df["cat"], boxmean="sd",))
```

I'm using `go.Box` since I want to visualize the STD. This yields:

[image]

How can I set different colors of for the left and right box plots depending on the category?

Comment: FWIW, here's another question I had related to the same bigger challenge I have: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72110370/671013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color by looping through each category variable.

```
for c in df['cat'].unique():
    dff = df[df['cat'] == c]
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=dff["val"], x=dff["cat"], boxmean="sd", name=c))
```

[image]

Comment: That worked nicely! It is a little counter intuitive for me that calling `fig.add_trace` twice behaves this way. I was expecting some sort of overwrite. But it is actually appending (adding as the name suggest) to the figure. It seems that the order `a`, `b` is kept regardless of their order in the loop. Interesting. Now I'm left with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72110370/671013).